# Why both DSolve and NDSolve are unable to solve a second-order differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, recursion

I am trying to solve a recurrence relation using generating functions method:
$$a_n=a_{n-1}+(n-1)a_{n-2}+(0.5n^2-1.5n+1)a_{n-3}$$

After some long calculations, I have arrived to this second-order differential equation:
$$0.5 x^5 y''(x)+(2x^4+x^3)y'(x)+\left(x^3+x^2+x-1\right)y(x)+1=0$$

and these conditions: $y(0)=1, y'(0)=1$. $y(x)$ is the function that needs to be expanded as Taylor Series at $x=0$ to obtain the sequence from the coefficients.
However, when I try to solve it both using DSolve and NDSolve, I have no luck. With DSolve it just returns the request itself:

$$\text{DSolve}\left[\left\{0.5 x^5 y''(x)+(2. x+1) x^3 y'(x)+\left(1. x^3+x^2+x-1\right)y(x)+1=0,y(0)=1,y'(0)=1\right\},y,x\right]$$

And with NDSolve I just receive errors and no equation:

```
Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0.^5 encountered.
Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity encountered.
NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x == 0.`.
```

$$\text{NDSolve}\left[\left\{0.5 x^5 y''(x)+(2. x+1) x^3 y'(x)+\left(1. x^3+x^2+x-1\right)y(x)+1=0,y(0)=1,y'(0)=1\right\},y,\{x,0,1\}\right]$$

How could I resolve this problem?

Code:

```
Simplify[y[x] - (1 + x + 2 x^2)]
l = Expand[%]
Simplify[x (y[x] - (1 + x))]
r1 = Expand[%]
Simplify[x*D[x^2 (y[x] - 1), x] - x^2 (y[x] - 1)]
r2 = Expand[%]
Simplify[0.5 x*D[x*D[x^3*y[x], x], x] - 1.5 x*D[x^3*y[x], x] + 
  x^3*y[x]]
r3 = Expand[%]
eq = FullSimplify[r1 + r2 + r3 - l]
DSolve[{eq == 0, y[0] == 1}, y, x]
NDSolve[{eq == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Please post code that can be readily copy-pasted by anyone who wants to try and answer your question.

Comment: `NDSolve` fails here, because the ODE is singular at `x = 0`.  Try integrating from a slightly larger value of `x`, but even then expect some difficulties.

Comment: `RecurrenceTable[{a[n] == a[n - 1] + (n - 1) a[n - 2] + (n^2 - 3 n + 2)/2 a[n - 3], a[1] == 1, a[2] == 1, a[3] == 2}, a, {n, 11}]` yields `{1, 1, 2, 8, 22, 82, 334, 1370, 6338, 30692, 155722}`.

Comment: I'm starting from 0, a[0]==1, a[1]==1, a[2]==2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Error Corrected.

Because neither `DSolve` nor `AsymptoticDSolveValue` produced a solution, I expanded the ODE itself and computed the coefficients of each term.

```
nmax = 10;
Normal@Series[x^5  y''[x]/2 + (2 x + 1) x^3 y'[x] + (x^3 + x^2 + x - 1) y[x] + 1, 
    {x, 0, nmax}]
CoefficientList[%, x] /. Derivative[n_][y][0] -> c[n] /. y[0] -> c[0]
Flatten@Solve[Thread[% == 0], Array[c, nmax + 1, 0]] // Values
%/(Range[0, nmax]!)

(* {1, 1, 2, 5, 14, 46, 166, 652, 2780, 12644, 61136} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

When I rationalize `eq`, `AsymptoticDSolveValue` returns a solution for me:

```
eq = FullSimplify[r1 + r2 + r3 - l]
```

> ```
> 1 + (-1 + x + x^2 + x^3) y[x] + x^3 (1 + 2 x) y'[x] + 1/2 x^5 y''[x]
> ```

```
seq = CoefficientList[
 AsymptoticDSolveValue[{eq == 0, y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 30}],
 x]
```

> ```
> (*
> {1, 1, 2, 5, 14, 46, 166, 652, 2780, 12644, 61136, 312676, 1680592, \
> 9467680, 55704104, 341185496, 2170853456, 14314313872, 97620050080, \
> 687418278544, 4989946902176, 37286121988256, 286432845428192, \
> 2259405263572480, 18280749571449664, 151561941235370176, \
> 1286402259593355776, 11168256342434121152, 99099358725069658880, \
> 898070590439513534464, 8306264068494786829696}
> *)
> ```

And `FindSequenceFunction` returns the original recursion:

```
an = FindSequenceFunction[%]
```

> ```
> (*
> DifferenceRoot[
>  Function[{\[FormalY], \[FormalN]}, {-\[FormalN] (1 + \[FormalN]) \
> \[FormalY][\[FormalN]] + (-2 - 2 \[FormalN]) \[FormalY][
>        1 + \[FormalN]] - 2 \[FormalY][2 + \[FormalN]] + 
>      2 \[FormalY][3 + \[FormalN]] == 0, \[FormalY][1] == 
>     1, \[FormalY][2] == 1, \[FormalY][3] == 2}]]
> *)
> ```

```
Table[an[n+1], {n, 0, 30}]
```

> ```
> (*  same as above: 1, 1, 2, 5, 14...  *)
> ```

I guess I'm not sure what exactly is being sought, though.

Comment: Nice soluton (+1).  I tried `AsymptoticDSolveValue[{x^5 y''[x]/2 + (2 x + 1) x^3 y'[ x] + (x^3 + x^2 + x - 1) y[x] + 1 == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 1}]` instead, which returned unevaluated.  Any idea why inclusion of `y'[0] == 1` caused `AsymptoticDSolveValue` to fail?

Comment: @bbgodfrey  I guess it has to do with $x=0$ being an irregular singular point. I'm not well-acquainted irregular singular points.  But try a higher order, such as `AsymptoticDSolveValue[{eq == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 2}]`.  (I don't actually recall removing `y'[0] == 1`, and it may have been carelessness on my part in copying code. But it worked and I didn't catch it.)

Comment: Amazing! `{x, 0, 1}` and `x -> 0` don't work, but `{x, 0, 2}` and higher do.  A bug?

Comment: @bbgodfrey I don't know (whether a bug).  Possibly a heuristic about how far to develop the series to solve for the order 1 leads to some problem; however, `SeriesTermGoal` does not help.

Comment: How were you able to display the results fully? When using CoefficientList I am getting precise values until 1680592, where I start to get approximate answers times 10^n. I'm using Mathematica 12.0.0, if that helps

Comment: @MichaelMykhaylov Did you "rationalize" the floating-point coefficients (i.e., change `0.5` to `1/2` and `1.5` to `3/2`)? (bbgodfrey did this, too.) I gave the value of `eq` that I used in the first output line in my answer. You should use this and avoid floating point. Floating point cannot represent integers exactly above around `10^16`, and Mathematica displays only the first six digits of FP numbers. You can see the complete number if you convert it to `InputForm` or `FullForm`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I have a new guess. If $y=y_p+y_g$ is the solution to the inhomogeneous `eq == 0`, where $y_g=c_1y_1+c_2y_2$ is the general solution to the homogeneous equation, then the result from `{eq == 0, y[0] == 1}` is the particular solution $y_p$ that is the only one with a finite limit at $x=0$, because I think $y_g$ blows up at $x=0$ for all nontrivial values of the coefficients $(c_1,c_2)$. Whether that is connected to the failure of `AsymptoticDSolveValue` at order `1` I don't know.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, I mistakingly did. Thanks for the correction